# Fast way to compute barycentric lagrange interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Is there any fast way to compute the barycentric Lagrange interpolation using matlab?
something more faster than using repmat instead of for loops

Comment: Can you show us what you're doing now (code/minimal example)? "Fast" is obviously relative.

Comment: @DougLipinski I am going to use lagrange interpolation on chebyshev nodes. As i searched Barycentric Interpolation is a fast way to implement lagrange interpolation. Somewhere else i have read about Clenshaw method to do the interpolation on chebyshev node which is apparently faster than Barycentric since it uses FFT. Is that true? How can i use Clenshaw method?

Comment: I would suggest that you look into chebfun to see how it does barycentric interpolation. chebfun is really fast. chebfun overloads interp1 function to implement barycentric interpolation. Also see the book of Trefethen.